# jQuery getting .preventDefault() to work on generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm having a bit of a problem with getting the .preventDefault to work on some elements I am generating via JQuery.

I am getting a JSON file using the following code and putting the data into individual p elements:

```
$.getJSON(searchURL, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
                    var fullPlayerURL = "<p class='entry'>" + "<a href=" + playerURL + data.data[i].id + ">"
                        + "Nickname - " + data.data[i].nickname + "</a>" + "</p>"
                    $('#results').append(fullPlayerURL);
                }
            }
        });
}); //end getJSON
```

Then I'm using the following code to stop the link from redirecting when clicked (links to another JSON file):

```
$('.entry').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var linkClicked = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(linkClicked);
});
```

I don't know if it matters but `#results` is just an empty div.

Here's [all the code](http://jsfiddle.net/K3NBB/) if this isn't enough info (sorry it's such a mess).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need delegated event handlers for dynamic elements

```
$('#results').on('click', '.entry', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var linkClicked = $('a', this).attr("href");
    console.log(linkClicked);
});
```

Comment: You also could use `.ajaxStop()` or put the code into the `success` function, just saying. @adoneo's solution is proper!

Comment: Just a quick question, how come `linkClicked` returns undefined in the console?

Comment: @DigitalMockingbird - The paragraph doesn't have a href attribute, the anchor inside does, edited the answer.

Comment: @DigitalMockingbird `$(this)` is now `#results`. Take `$(event.target).attr("href")`. Adeneo?

Comment: @dollarvar - nope, `this` is `.entry`, jQuery keeps the right scope for delegated handler as well, but the `.entry` element is not the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not allowed to comment on adeneo's answer.
For me `var linkClicked = $('a', this).attr("href");` gives undefined.
I had to make `var linkClicked = $(this).attr("href");` out of it.

Edit: Know it, I wanted to address the anchor.

```
$('#results').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var linkClicked = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(linkClicked);
});
```